# PHP basic: How to access a member of an attribute of an object

Tags: php, operators

I have this output when I do var_dump($myvar) on a variable.

```
    object(stdClass)#5 (19) {
      ["contributors"]=>
      NULL
      ["coordinates"]=>
      NULL
      ...
      ...
      ...
      ["text"]=>
      string(118) "Tune in to @Current TV this Saturday for post-debate commentary from me + @JenGranholm + Cenk Uygur #PoliticallyDirect"
    }
```

How do I reach the "text" attribute? I thought it would be $myvar["text"] but that gives me this error message:

Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Comment: *(reference)* http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the member names are simple, you can use the `->` operator:

```
echo $myvar->text;
```

You can use an alternate syntax to access members names that contain special characters (JSON decoded data often produces such cases):

```
echo $myvar->{'some-other-text-with-hyphens'};
```

Answer (score 5):

You have an object of `stdClass`, use the dereference/object-access operator:

```
echo $myvar->text;
```