# How to decode this

Tags: php, object

I am new to PHP, I am trying to learn it. Actually, I am not getting what is this format and how to get the result from it. below is my code after var_dump:

```
$data = some array();
var_dump($data);
/*
 object(stdClass)#58 (3) {
    ["jsonrpc"]=> string(3) "2.0"
    ["id"]=> int(1)
    ["result"]=> string(42) "Success"
} 
*/
```

Now I want the 'result' parameter only as a string. I am trying to do this way:

```
$reult = $data['result'];
```

but it is giving  `Illegal string offset 'result'` error.

Comment: try `$data->result`. If it works, it's not an array but a [`StdClass`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931407/what-is-stdclass-in-php). If it doesn't work, something else is wrong in your code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP basic: How to access a member of an attribute of an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8451248/php-basic-how-to-access-a-member-of-an-attribute-of-an-object)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo $data->result;
```

You can use this to echo the object value

Or you can cast it as array

```
var_dump( (array) $data);
$data=(array) $data;
echo $data[result];
```

Answer (score -1):

Your data is a [PHP stdClass](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php). In my opinion you should [convert it to array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44453682/5938111). After that you can easily use it.